# CentOS 6 vps configuration

Tags: centos, web-server, configuration, vps, centos6

I have a vps server with CentOS 6, I want to know how can I configure it and prepare it to add my domain and add my files.

the problem is that I'm a beginner to Linux, and I want the right way to understand.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You have to be MUCH more specific in order for us to help you (see [How To Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask)-- if you're looking for guides/tutorials Google is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to setup using the following guide:
[LAMP Server on CentOS 6](http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/centos-6)